# Cannot redirect Yubikey into VMWare Horizon VDI with Ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, vdi, yubikey

I am not able to redirect to Yubikey into the VMWare Horizon VDI. the guest OS is Ubuntu 20.04 I have install the vmware client & the required driver with the following command:

```
sudo ./install_viewagent.sh -m yes -U yes -A yes
sudo apt install yubico-piv-tool yubikey-manager yubikey-personalization-gui libpam-yubico libpam-u2f
```

I am able to show the Yubikey is inserted with command, but the Yubikey manager cannot detect the device with the GUI. pls find the enclosed screenshot

[image]

```
sudo pcsc_scan
```

Note: I can redirect the Yubikey to VMWare Player with Ubuntu 20.04 OS with the setting modified in vmx file:

```
usb.ccid.disable = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowCCID = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowLastHID = "TRUE"
```